# Config grunt-contrib-sass to keep all comments

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I'm writing a mini CSS framework for myself, I use Sass to write the source code, and grunt([grunt-contrib-sass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-sass)) to compile my final "framework-name.scss" to "framework-name.css".

The problem is Both "//" and "/* ...  */" style comments are used in my scss files, and grunt-contrib-sass only keep "/* ... */" ones and trim the "//", and the output just don't make sense and looks ugly.

I want to config grunt-contrib-sass to either keep all comments or trim them all(I prefer keeping them all, and use cssmin to trim all comments when exporting the compressed css).

But after I read the grunt-contrib-sass docs I found out there's no way to config this option, though I could just look for other compilation tool, but I am just familiar with Grunt.

So help me out, is there some ways to achieve what I want in Grunt, or I should simply unify my comments styles in scss files? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem resides in the actual SASS converter, not the Grunt task `grunt-contrib-sass`.

From the SASS language reference:

> Sass supports standard multiline CSS comments with `/* */`, as well as single-line comments with `//`. The multiline comments are preserved in the CSS output where possible, while the single-line comments are removed.

There is no way to configure this on the SASS converter.

The reason is that single-line comments are actually comments for the SASS code. You should describe variables and mixins with single-line comments. They are meant to be meaningful only in SASS context.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks for help! Guess I should ajust my comments style.

Comment: Cleary [SASS docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments) has a section explain how SASS treats comments, It's my bad I haven't noticed that yet. Thanks again.